# SSIS conditional split - condition setting

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, conditional-split

It's one of my practice stuff, setting the condition to split the scariness of rollercoasters. 
However, it didn't work properly as it did not split the default output which is set as "Not scary". 
I think something wrong with my second condition, but cannot figure out how to correct that.
Here is the required condition:

- `Very scary` :   The "Speed" column is more than 50.
- `Quite scary` :  Either the    coaster's "Type" column is Wood, or the
  "Design" column is not Sit    Down.
- `Not scary` :    Any other coasters failing the first two conditions    (the
  default output).

And here is the condition I wrote:

1. `Very scary     [Speed ( mph )] > 50`
2. `Quite scary        Type == "wood" || Design != "sit down"`

The result didn't show any "not scary" even when type does not equal to wood or design equals to site down

Please help me out, appreciate that! thank you :)

Comment: please screenshot the conditional split editor to show the conditions in full and this is likely to help get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your conditional split looks fine but note that SSIS expressions `==` operator are [case sensitive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138047.aspx) so you can convert all values to UPPER Case

```
Quite scary:        UPPER([Type]) == "WOOD" || UPPER([Design]) != "SIT DOWN"
```

Comment: Problem solved! I was not aware of the case sensitive part. Thank you so much :)